# Pin Secondary tiles

Tags: win-universal-app

According to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465398.aspx):

> Only users can pin a secondary tile to the Start screen; apps can't programmatically pin secondary tiles

what does it mean? because I can pin my application to start screen by this code:

```
    secondaryTile.RequestCreateAsync();
```

Comment: I've deleted the answer as it's probably not complete. [Seems like depending on device type and operating system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br242213.aspx), the behavior may vary a little.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that documentation meant to say...

> Secondary Tiles should only be pinned as a result of direct user interaction (like clicking a Pin button in your app).

In Windows 8.1, your users will see that dialog displaying a preview of the tile, confirming whether they'd like to pin it. In Windows Phone 8.1, the tile will be automatically pinned and the user will be taken to the Start Screen, showing them the new tile. In Windows 10 Desktop, the user will see a "Did you mean to pin this to Start?" dialog, which they have to click yes in order to pin the tile. In Windows 10 Mobile, the tile will be silently pinned and your app will remain in the foreground.